# Laravel 4.1 Blade + Handlerbar escaping issue (%20, %7B etc ..)

Tags: laravel-4, handlebars.js, laravel-blade

I'm working with Laravel 4.1 (recently update to) and Handlebars.

I have a view where I mix Blade template and Handlebars template.

My problem is that this line:

```
<a href="{{{ url('event',array('id' => '@{{id}}')) }}}">View</a>
```

return me this :

```
http://local/event/%7B%7Bid%7D%7D
```

instate of :

```
http://local/event/7 (if id = 7)
```

Note that this line return the correct value :

```
<span>@{{id}}</span>
```

The issue occurs only in the url() Laravel helper :(

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In my case the workaround is:
    <a href="{{ url('event') }}/@{{id}}">View</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant get Handlebars to put the $id there - because it is a Laravel PHP function url() that must resolve first, and the result is passed to Handlebars.

i.e. this would work:

```
<a href="http://yoururl.com/event/@{{id}}">View</a>
```

But you cant get Handlebars to use an ID in the Laravel function.

What you are trying to do in your example is get Laravel to pass a URL to Handlebars, Handlebars inserts the ID, then Laravel finishes the function - which wont work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what is strange is that, this code worked with Laravel 4.0! I saw this issue occurring after the update to Laravel 4.1

Comment: Really? I dont see how. Maybe someone else can answer with other info - but I dont think it can work that way.

Comment: I think that before, the blade template system returned something like
http://mylink.com/event/{{id}} and this code was compilable by Handlebar.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the workaround is

```
<a href="{{ url('event') }}/@{{id}}">View</a>
```